# printing the output it is showing error in line, rest output is correct

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault, cs50

in the first line it is printing 64 instead pf 0100, it tried to change the value and I noticed that if i put 0 at first place then the output is sum of every digit to to power of 8.
And if 0 is not in starting then it is printing the same number.
help me on this , whats the issue.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{  

    typedef struct node
    {
        int num;
        struct node *next;
    }
    node;
    node* list = NULL;

    node *n1 = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (n1 != NULL)
    {
        n1 -> num = 111111; 
        n1 -> next = NULL;  
    }

    list = n1;
    node *n2 = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (n2 != NULL)
    {
        n2 -> num = 22222;
        n2 -> next = NULL;
        n1 -> next = n2;
    }

    // addind n3 in middle of n1 n2

    node *n3 = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (n3 != NULL)
    {
        n3 -> num = 33333;
        n3 -> next = n2;
        n2 -> next = NULL;
        n1 -> next = n3;
    }

    // ADDIND TO THE END OF LIST

    node *n4 = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (n4 != NULL)
    {
        n4 -> num = 444;
        n4 -> next = NULL;
        node *tmp1 = NULL;
        tmp1 = list;

        while (tmp1 -> next != NULL)
        {
            tmp1 = tmp1 -> next;
        }
        tmp1 -> next = n4;
    }

    // ADDING TO THE STARTING OF LIST   

    node *n5 = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (n5 != NULL)
    {
        n5 -> num = 0100;
        n5 -> next = list;
        list = n5;
    }

    node *tmp = list;
    while(tmp != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d\n", tmp -> num);
        tmp = tmp -> next;
    }

}
```

OUTPUT IS

```
64

111111

33333

22222

444
```

Comment: When you use a debugger, what is the *first* thing the program does wrong?

Comment: It seems you should use `const char* num;` instead of `int num;` and `n5 -> num = "0100";` instead of `n5 -> num = 0100;`. Also change other assignmens to `nx -> num` to assignments of strings and `printf("%d\n", tmp -> num);` to `printf("%s\n", tmp -> num);`.

Answer (score 0):

In C, integer literals start with `0` and don't start with `0x` nor `0X` are treated as octal numbers.

You cannot get original strings from integers, so you should store your data as strings if you want to retain strings like that.

To do that:

- Change type of `num` from `int` to `const char*`.
- Change data to assign from integers to strings.
- Change format specifier for `printf()` to print strings.

Fixed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{  

    typedef struct node
    {
        const char* num;
        struct node *next;
    }
    node;
    node* list = NULL;

    node *n1 = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (n1 != NULL)
    {
        n1 -> num = "111111"; 
        n1 -> next = NULL;  
    }

    list = n1;
    node *n2 = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (n2 != NULL)
    {
        n2 -> num = "22222";
        n2 -> next = NULL;
        n1 -> next = n2;
    }

    // addind n3 in middle of n1 n2

    node *n3 = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (n3 != NULL)
    {
        n3 -> num = "33333";
        n3 -> next = n2;
        n2 -> next = NULL;
        n1 -> next = n3;
    }

    // ADDIND TO THE END OF LIST

    node *n4 = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (n4 != NULL)
    {
        n4 -> num = "444";
        n4 -> next = NULL;
        node *tmp1 = NULL;
        tmp1 = list;

        while (tmp1 -> next != NULL)
        {
            tmp1 = tmp1 -> next;
        }
        tmp1 -> next = n4;
    }

    // ADDING TO THE STARTING OF LIST   

    node *n5 = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (n5 != NULL)
    {
        n5 -> num = "0100";
        n5 -> next = list;
        list = n5;
    }

    node *tmp = list;
    while(tmp != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n", tmp -> num);
        tmp = tmp -> next;
    }

}
```

output:

```
0100
111111
33333
22222
444
```